# How to get the object with its translation using getRoute in Symfony?

Tags: routes, model, symfony1, translation

I have several models with translations. When I load

```
$this->tour = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
```

por example, it gets me the Tour Object. However, it doesn't join to the tour_translation table; so when after i try to get it's title; symfony makes another sql query.

How I can override something, so in the Tour model when I ask for the object, it returns me the object with its translation in the current culture.

I've been looking at the [sfObjectRoute class](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.2/lib/routing/sfObjectRoute.class.php) to see if I can override any method, but I'm not sure right now

I know I can do the following, but I prefer the first option as it's more transparent and elegant:

```
$this->tour = Tour::getTour($request->getParameter('id'), $lang);
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify in your route definition what method to use when retrieving the object through the `method`option:

```
my_route
  url: /tour/:id
  options:
    model: Tour
    type: object
    method: getTourForRoute
```

(`params` section skipped for brevity sake)

Be aware that the method will not receive the `id` directly as a parameter but an array of parameters passed to the route, thus you would write a method like that:

```
public function getTourForRoute($parameters)
{
  return self::getTour($parameters['id']);
}
```

Final note: this option is only available if you use either a `sfDoctrineRoute` or a `sfPropelRoute` :-)